# Select One column Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql, doctrine-1.2

I need a simple column for a table.

By example a table "project", with column `id`, `name` and `year`.

If I do:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('a.pro_id')
        ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
        ->where('a.pro_id =?',1);
    $pro = $q->execute();
    json_encode($pro->toArray());
```

The answer is all column like

```
{"id":1,"name":"Project name","year":2013}
```

but I need only one column. I expect:

```
{"id":1}
```

It is with DQL because with native SQL work fine.

The ORM is build automaticaly with a Visual Paradigm.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is because Doctrine hydrate the response with all the object information, so all columns.

You need to use a different hydration method, [there are many one](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/data-hydrators.html), but let's focus on 5 of them:

- `HYDRATE_RECORD`, the default one
- `HYDRATE_ARRAY`
- `HYDRATE_NONE`
- `HYDRATE_SCALAR`
- `HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW`

You need the `HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW` hydration method. Here's why.

1. **HYDRATE_RECORD**

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('a.pro_id')
       ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
       ->where('a.pro_id = ?',1);
   $pro = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD);
   var_dump(json_encode($pro->toArray()));
   ```

   This will hydrate the result using object, and also hydrate relations (if you use a leftJoin inside your query). Since it returns object, we need to call `toArray()` to be able to send a propre json:

   ```
   [{"id":1,"name":"Project name","year":2013}]"
   ```
2. **HYDRATE_ARRAY**

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('a.pro_id')
       ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
       ->where('a.pro_id = ?',1);
   $pro = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
   var_dump(json_encode($pro));
   ```

   This will hydrate result as an array an automatically add the primary key:

   ```
   [{"id":"1","pro_id":"1"}]"
   ```
3. **HYDRATE_NONE**

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('a.pro_id')
       ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
       ->where('a.pro_id = ?',1);
   $pro = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE);
   var_dump(json_encode($pro));
   ```

   This won't hydrate result, and return just values:

   ```
   [["1"]]"
   ```
4. **HYDRATE_SCALAR**

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('a.pro_id')
       ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
       ->where('a.pro_id = ?',1);
   $pro = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
   var_dump(json_encode($pro));
   ```

   This will hydrate result from the select but with key index as the column name with the table alias:

   ```
   [{"a_pro_id":"1"}]"
   ```
5. **HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW**

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('a.pro_id')
       ->from('fndr_proyecto a')
       ->where('a.pro_id = ?',1);
   $pro = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_SHALLOW);
   var_dump(json_encode($pro));
   ```

   This will hydrate result from the select but with key index as the column name without the table alias:

   ```
   "[{"pro_id":"1"}]"
   ```

Comment: Of course! Now find the chapter in the documentation "Data Hydrators". I did not know of that it was about the subject.
Thank you very much! ;)

Comment: @h3g0r_ try them, array hydration is often faster and lighter than record hydration !

Comment: Very good explanation, I've always been puzzled about how works the hydrators, but now all is clear in my mind. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

As of Doctrine 2.10, you can use [Scalar Column Hydration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#scalar-column-hydration):

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a.id FROM CmsUser u');
$ids = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR_COLUMN);
```

or

```php
$ids = $query->getSingleColumnResult();
```

and this results in a flat array

```
[412, 959, 1234]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what version of Doctrine j0k was using.  It provided some answers, but I did have trouble finding  Doctrine_Query and Doctrine_Core classes.    I am using Doctrine 2.3.4.  The following worked for me.

```
public static function getAllEventIDs($em) {
    return parent::getAllFromColumn('\path\to\Entity\entityName', 'id', $em);
}

public static function getAllFromColumn($tableName, $columnName, $em) {
    $q = $em->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select("t.$columnName")
    ->from($tableName, 't');

    $q = $q->getQuery();

    $result = $q->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);

    return $result;
}
```

This did however return a array of arrays.  ie, the id of the first event was is

```
$result[0]['id'];
```